# Sklearn MiniBatchKMeans gives confusing results for labels_ attribute

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I am using [sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html) for training an ML model. I need to get cluster ids of clusters and I tried with the below code. (Here *model* is the MiniBatchKmeans Clustering model)

```
print("Cluster IDs: ", np.unique(model.labels_))
print("Number of Clusters: ", model.n_clusters)
```

I got the following result.

```
Cluster IDs:  [0]
Number of Clusters:  2
```

According to this result, it shows that there is only 1 cluster-id for the given dataset and still there are 2 clusters. I found that all the new data(2nd training phase) I used to train the model using *partial_fit* function were assigned to one cluster. It seems like cluster centers are updated properly but, *transform* function gives confusing results for the distance vector. What is the reason for this?