# Trained model of scikit-learn Mini Batch Kmeans doesn't contain all the labels

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm currently working on a python machine learning project which has to learn behaviors from input data requests (data is sent through HTTP POST requests). My algorithm fetches input data one by one and calls `partial_fit` function on scikit-learn Mini Batch KMeans model. Here's the brief procedure.

1. gather 5 data requests.
2. call partial_fit function on collected data.
3. save the model.

According to the definition, my Kmeans model is supposed to have 3 clusters. However, the trained model only returned a single label when `model.labels_` is called. But `model.cluster_centers_` returned an array list related to three clusters. Any help or explanation to overcome this problem would be appreciated.

Here is the related code segment.

```
kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=3, init='k-means++', max_iter=800, random_state=50)

# re-train and save the model
# newly fethched data are stored in dataframe variable (Pandas dataframe).
kmeans = pickle.load(open(model.sav, 'rb'))
kmeans.partial_fit(dataframe)
pickle.dump(kmeans,open('model.sav'), 'wb'))
```

Here is the result I got.

[image]

Comment: where do you run your `model`on?

Comment: and why do you open the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58056942/sklearn-minibatchkmeans-gives-confusing-results-for-labels-attribute

Comment: Your input data is biased/similar type and the model is unable to predict the same in different clusters.You should check your training data points and try to plot the data.

Comment: @PV8 I run it on a flask server.